# How do I get the instance of a templated item from a databound ItemsControl? (WPF)

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datatemplate, itemscontrol, contentpresenter

I have an `<ItemsControl>` with a custom `<DataTemplate>` (and also a custom `<ItemsPanelTemplate>` that is just a `WrapPanel`), bound via `ItemsSource` to a simple observable collection of strings.

The `DataTemplate` consists simply of an instance of a custom `UserControl` whose properties are bound to the string via `{Binding}`.

The problem is since my data items are just strings, I need to access the instances of my `UserControl` directly programmatically, but I can't seem to figure out how!

I've tried:

```
var item = tagBar.Items[ tagBar.Items.Count - 1 ];
```

...but that just returns the string. Also:

```
var item2 = tagBar.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex( tagBar.Items.Count - 1 );
```

...returns a `ContentPresenter`, and I can't figure out what to do with the `ContentPresenter` to get to the instance of my `UserControl`.

??

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283943/find-ui-element-corresponding-to-an-item-in-a-silverlight-itemscontrol), but it was never properly answered, and was also specific to Silverlight whereas this is WPF.

Comment: Before someone suggests it, item2.Content just returns the string also. *sigh*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer I've posted [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/329556/focus-on-textbox-in-datatemplate#329571) deals with focusing an element inside a DataTemplate, but it should provide the code you need. It involves using the FindName method on your DataTemplate to find a control within it. If you give your UserControl a name you should be right.

Comment: Excellent, that did it! The key was passing `item` (or rather `item2` in my above code) back into `tagBar.ItemTemplate.FindName()` (and of course, giving the `UserControl` a name to be found by).

I'll also be careful with the IsLoaded bit, though that's kind of lame that it's needed.

Thanks!

Comment: @chaiguy1337 -- it looks like backtick support has been added since you wrote that, as the text comes through with formatting now.